# Recursively make one level array from multi levels array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I'm confused a little, please help me anyone.
This is what I have

```
var arr = [
  1,
  2,
  [11, 12, 13],
  3,
  [11, 12, 
       [21, 22]
  ]
];
```

As you can see, it's multi-lever array. Using recursion I need to make a one level array from it, which contains all elements from its children. Should be like this:

```
[1,2,11,12,13,3,11,12,21,22]
```

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
function getAllNumbers(arr) {
    var allNumbers = [];
    arr.forEach(function (el) {
        if (Array.isArray(el)) {
            allNumbers.concat(getAllNumbers(el))
        } else {
            allNumbers.push(el)
        }
    });
    return allNumbers;
}
```

and it's not working. Gives me back only first level, like this: `[1,2,3]`
I'm particularly interested in **recursion** so please don't try to find other way.

please help

**P.S.** I can easily find sum of all elements with similar method just a little modified, but cannot do this :(

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything was fine :)
just

> The concat() method returns a new array comprised of the array on which it is called joined with the array(s) and/or value(s) provided as arguments.

so, instead of

```
allNumbers.concat(getAllNumbers(el))
```

should be

```
allNumbers = allNumbers.concat(getAllNumbers(el))
```

and it works :)